# how to make two functionality in one button.CSS BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi could anyone help me achieve this

[image]

this is my code so far

```
<button class="btn btn-add btn-block">button</button>
```

and I add custom css

```
.btn-add{
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 11px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: block;
    width: 250px;

}
```

with my code i achieve the button without the x on upper right corner

I needed to have button like in the image cos:

*when I click the button It shoul lead me to another page 
*when I click the x on the upper right corner of my button I will delete the button.

but I only need the css on how to achieve this.

could anyone help me I'm not well rounded on my css thanks in advance.

this is my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PFL4N/)

Comment: i would make two buttons one on top of the other

Comment: my senior requires me to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply position one button over another, and style accordingly:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4YyMF/2/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <button>button</button>
    <button>x</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
button {
    border:none;
}
button:first-child {
    background:lightgrey;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:times;
    padding:30px;
}
button:last-child {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:2px;
    width:25px;
    background:grey;
    color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.closeIcon{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('/static/images/close_small.png') no-repeat;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    right: -16px;
}
```